# Can't Add Div to Page

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to add another div to my site and for some reason i can not it, ive added the div and css but its not affecting the result.

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/N8yyz/embedded/result/

Html:

```
<div id="fourthsection1">


</div>
```

css:

```
#fourthsection1{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That div is behind "container" !

Comment: Yes its very weird that! let me take a look

Comment: If you remove "thirdsubsection1&2" you'll see it.

Comment: I can't seem to get it out of the container! Any ideas?

Comment: @Vucko any ideas whats causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a div with style="clear:both" after thirdsubsection1&2 !

Comment: After floating you must clear the areas whom were floated.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this by adding `overflow:hidden` to the container element inside `#thirdsection` on chrome.

A better solution would be to use clearfix. I would take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) question for ideas.

Comment: Hmm i'm not having the same luck! how did you implement it?